# ¿Cómo usar Cookies AJAX en todo un dominio?

Tags: ajax, jwt, dominio, cookies

Muy buenas a todos, mi pregunta es la siguiente: tengo una aplicación web SPA con `Spring MVC` + `Hibernate` + `jjwt` en el lado backend y `AngularJS` para dar las vistas. Autentico a los clientes con `JSON Web Tokens` almacenados en Cookies en el lado del cliente por supuesto. Quiero usar las opciones `secure` y `httpOnly` por lo que la Cookie no puedo 'setearla' con `AngularJS` al tener la opción `httpOnly`.

Esto me deja la única opción de que la cookie sea seteada por el propio navegador al realizar la petición AJAX contra la API del servidor web. El problema que tuve aquí es que al usar la aplicación no recibia la cookie con el token json y buscando por esta magnífica web encontre que poniendo también el parametro `path=ruta_que_quiero_tener_la_cookie` me llegaba la cookie a la API web, pero esto no termina de resolver mi problema ya que necesito, como minimo, tener acceso a la cookie desde todo el dominio.

Si alguién puediera aclararme las dudas se lo agradezco desde este momento :-}

Comment: si alguien con +150 pudiera poner la etiqueta `cookie` gracias ya que creo que es la mas adecuada a la pregunta. :)

Comment: ya existe la etiqueta, se llama `cookies`

Comment: Pero yo no puedo ponerla @EmanuelVe  gracias!!

Comment: ¿Tu público final es amplio? Es decir, navegadores < IE 9. Porque es mucho más sencillo y además nativo de JavaScript usar local o sessionStorage para guardar el token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## He solucionado el problema

Al igual que como había dicho si ajustamos el parámetro de la cookie `path=ruta_que_quiero_tener_la_cookie` en dicha ruta, aunque la cookie fuera originalmente creada y recibida de `path2` siendo `path2!=path` tendríamos acceso a ella en `path`.

Usando en este caso `domain=dominion_de_mi_app` tengo acceso a la cookie en todas las URL de mi aplicación, por lo que la pregunta queda respondida. Gracias a todos.